# Add image to smart art layout through c#?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am wondering is there a way to add image to smart art through c#. So far, with a google search, I found how to add text like below:

```
PowerPoint.Shape shape= oSlide.Shapes.AddSmartArt(oSlide.Application.SmartArtLayouts[3], 10, 125);

shape.SmartArt.Nodes[1].TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "check";
```

But I am not sure how to include picture.

Answer (score 0):

ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(1).SmartArt.Nodes(2).Shapes(1).Fill.UserPicture "path and file name"

Please refer this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/102fbf9a-4279-4bb8-a36b-ad4cb543aeb1/add-image-to-smart-art-layout-through-c)